# limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

How do I show it's limit is $0$?

I thought about:

$$\frac{xy}{\|(x,y)\|} \le \frac{xy}{|x|} \le \frac{xy}{x} \le y \to 0$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Observe that $\;\left|\frac x{|x|}\right|\le 1\;$ is bounded, so $$\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\frac x{|x|}y\xrightarrow[y\to 0]{}0$$ as bounded times something that goes to zero goes to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks fine.

As I wrote in [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098694/is-this-a-correct-use-of-the-squeeze-theorem/), usually it is useful to set $x = \rho \cos \theta$, $y = \rho \sin \theta$ and taking the limit as $\rho \to 0$. More specifically, if you find that 
$|f(\rho \cos \theta, \rho \sin \theta)| \le g(\rho) \to 0$, then you showed that $f(x, y) \to 0$

In your case

$$|f(\rho \cos \theta, \rho \sin \theta)| = \frac{|\rho^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta|}{|\rho|} \le \rho = g(\rho) \to 0$$

so your limit is indeed $0$

Answer (score -5):

Wrong answer

Actually,it has no limits.
From different directions to (0,0),it's limit is different.
 For example:(x,0) to (0,0),the limit is 0;(t,t) to (0,0),the limit is 1/sqrt(2)

Comment: From what paths exactly?I think you're wrong

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: For your second instance, you would have $ \frac{t \ \cdot \ t}{\sqrt{t^2 \ + \ t^2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{t^2}{t \ \sqrt{2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{t}{ \sqrt{2}} \ $ , which will also goes to zero as $ \ t \ \rightarrow \ 0 \ $ .

Comment: Oh,you are right,I made a mistake.i mistake this with xy/(x^2+y^2)